# How to combine Date and Time objects into DateTime object?

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, object-oriented

Considering a DateObject `d` and TimeObject `t`:

```
In[1]:= t = TimeObject[{14, 1, 45.`}]
In[2]:= d = DateObject[{2012, 06, 11}]
```

How can I achieve this result:

```
In[3]:= dt = DateObject[{2012, 06, 11, 14, 1, 45.`}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another, shorter way is

```
Append[d, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the docs,

> `DateObject[date,time]` represents the specified date list and `TimeObject` time.

If you need the list you mention in the question, just convert the `DateObject` using `DateList`:

```
DateList@Append[d, t]
(* {2012, 6, 11, 14, 1, 45.} *)
```

Comment: Tidiest one yet! :)

Comment: That's real nice.

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party here but this also works:

```
In[28]:= DateObject[d, t]
```

as Szabolcs noted, the documentation references this, but doesn't give an explicit example(which I will make sure gets added).

Answer (score 3):

Strip off their heads. replace them with `List` and then `Flatten` them:

```
dt=DateObject@@(List @@@ {d, t} // Flatten)
```

> DateObject[{2012, 6, 11, 14, 1, 45.}]

Or ....

```
dt=DateObject @@ Join @@ {d[[1]], t[[1]]}
```

Comment: Why is the result no quantity/object, but only text?

Comment: My bad, it's early for me ;)

Comment: Why not `Join[]` the lists instead? :)

Comment: See recent update :)

Comment: Well, I had `DateObject @@ Join[d[[1]], t[[1]]]`, myself… :)

Comment: I think that's one hole to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
d~d[[0]]~t
```

...seems to work.